# how to get better (any?) diagnostics out of ninject why its throwing ActivationException?

Tags: ninject

Ok, so I am using both Automapper (LOVE it!) and ninject (very fond of it, but we have "issues" :-).  I am writing MVC3 apps.

When I mess something up in Automapper configuration, Automapper goes to great lengths to tell me exactly what I did wrong, providing all necessary details.

When I mess something up in ninject configuration, it says "something is wrong".  Well, not even quite that.  If I am lucky enough to have the output window open, I hopefully see a message fly by akin to "first chance exception ActivationException was thrown".  Thats it.

Not very helpful if you ask me...

Is there a way to get ninject to be a little more communicative?  Right now, I have a list of things I check (make sure ctor is public, make sure the class implements all of the interface, etc etc).

Comment: Ninject throws exceptions as its way of talking and there's a lot of effort going into making them extremely helpful. Start catching them, and show us one that didnt give you what you needed!

Comment: OK, so that tells me I am doing something wrong then.  Is there some kind of configuration option I need to do when I create the kernel or bind an interface to a concrete class.
I assume I would put a try/catch around the creation of a class that takes an interface which is bound in its constructor?  And I want to catch ActivationException.

Comment: OK, I just put a try/catch around my TryGet call, and it does not throw an exception (any exception).  Ill try to post some source code later, but it is pretty much directly modelled on code out of Steve Sandersons MVC3 book.
I am obviously doing something wrong, so please bear with me :-)

Comment: Adding try/catches around DI code is not something you want to end up doing. Global Exception handling / logging is best handled outside of your DI concerns - something like ELMAH and/or looking for a global exception handling in ASP.NET article / question here is the best tack to take rather than me trundling out a general answer on this.

Comment: wholeheartedly agreed that try/catch around di code aint the way to go, especially since a di exception is generally indicative of "internal coding error".  Already have global exception handling, but my problem was that the exceptions weren't actually getting thrown.  See my below answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!  Found the issue.

Turns out that I am using `TryGet()`, which implicitly catches any exceptions ninject throws.  This explains why although I saw a message about a first chance exception in the output log, but nothing was actually thrown.

Switching over to using a `Get()` lets the exception bubble up.

Now theres a whole lotta love im gettin' from ninject about the error in my ways  ==> very useful diagnostic debug output.

Hope this helps another soul with the same confusion.

Comment: If you turn on first chance exception trapping via the Ctrl-Alt-E mentu and/or turn off Just My Code, you can do a Shift F9 QuickWatch of `$exception` to view it even in that case - but obv `TryGet` isnt what you want here

Comment: Normally TryGet shouldn't throw an exception not even internal. There are some special cases though were we haven't found an other solution than trowing and catching an exception but as I said they are rare.

Comment: TryGet does not throw an exception outside itself.  But I do get a "First Chance exception, ActivationException thrown" inside my debugger output.  I dont know if one of the situations you are referring to is to forget to mark the ctor of the class that will get its ctor parameters injected as public, but that definitely causes the message.